# Cross-platform static-linking SDL2

Tags: static-linking, sdl-2

I'm building an SDL2/C++ program that needs to be portable to Windows, Mac, and Linux machines which may not have SDL installed.

I've read that static linking is the solution, but I'm not very good with compiling and don't know how to static link.

My program relies only on SDL2, GLU, and OpenGL. I'm compiling C++ with either MinGW (on Windows 8.1) or gcc (on Ubuntu 14.04) -- both of these OS's have SDL installed natively.

Here is my current makefile, derived from a sample makefile given to me by a professor of mine:

```
# Executable/file name
EXE=experiment

#  MinGW
ifeq "$(OS)" "Windows_NT"
CFLG=-O3 -Wall -DUSEGLEW
LIBS= -lSDL2 -lglu32 -lopengl32
CLEAN=del *.exe *.o *.a
else
#  OSX
ifeq "$(shell uname)" "Darwin"
CFLG=-O3 -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations
LIBS=-framework SDL2 -framework OpenGL
#  Linux\Unix\Solaris
else
CFLG=-O3 -Wall
LIBS= `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` -lGLU -lGL -lm
endif
#  OSX\Linux\Unix\Solaris
CLEAN=rm -f $(EXE) *.o *.a
endif

# Dependencies
$(EXE).o: $(EXE).cpp FORCE


.c.o:
    gcc -c -o $@ $(CFLG) $<
.cpp.o:
    g++ -std=c++11 -c -o $@ $(CFLG) $<

#  Link
$(EXE):$(EXE).o
    g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -o $@ $^   $(LIBS)

#  Clean
clean:
    $(CLEAN)

# Force
FORCE:
```

Comment: This question has been asked so many times, and not one person can answer it successfully. +1.

Answer (score 1):

To link with static library you either specify path to library file

`gcc -o out_bin your_object_files.o path/to/lib.a -lfoo`

or ask linker to use static version with `-Bstatic` linker flag. Usually you'll want to reset linking back to dynamic for the rest of the libraries, e.g. for static SDL2 and GLU but dynamic GL:

`gcc -o out_bin your_object_files -Wl,-Bstatic -lSDL2 -lGLU -Wl,-Bdynamic -lGL`

That of course implies that static versions of libraries are present in library search path list (`.a` libs for gcc on all specified platforms, although MSVC uses `.lib` for static libraries).

However you usually don't really want to do that at all. It is common practice for software to either depend on some libs (widespread on linux, with packages and dependendices lists) or bring required libraries with it. You can just distribute SDL dynamic library with your program and load it with LD_LIBRARY_PATH or relative rpath.

Please also note that newer SDL2 implements dynamic loading of functions which provides a way to override SDL with user-specified dynamic library, even if linked statically.

Comment: Thanks! But it seems that -Bstatic doesn't have the desired effect (it still looks for SDL2.dll at run time). Removing the "B" and the commas seems to fix this, but then it gives a plethora of undefined references. I saw another solution that when linking statically, you need to manually link to everything that SDL references (-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows -lm -ldinput8 -ldxguid -ldxerr8 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm -limm32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -lshell32 -lversion -luuid -static-libgcc). This compiles with no errors, but the program doesn't work.

Comment: It just runs silently in the background without opening a window. Do some of these new libraries need to be linked dynamically? I'm linking them all statically except for -lopengl32 and -lm.

Comment: I figured out that the program hangs when trying to use printf() and getline() to the stdio, instead of actually printing or receiving. This only happens when statically linking. Is there something peculiar about static linking with stdio?

Comment: @user258887 don't think it is, but you got link flags wrong. `-static` asks compiler to produce static binary with no dll links at all; `-Bstatic` **linker** option asks linker to use static versions of subsequent libraries, unless `-Bdynamic` specified. `-Wl` is gcc command to pass the rest of an option directly to likner (hence `-Wl,-Bstatic`, no spaces!). Just checked it on windows virtual machine and it works just as expected (depends on SDL2.dll without -Bstatic, doesn't with it, with huge difference in binary size)

Comment: Is there an advantage to static linking of certain libraries vs. creating a static binary? Right now the -static version is able to run on another machine, while the -Bstatic version still complains about missing DLLs. Neither of them is able to interact with stdio :/

Comment: Try running it in debugger. If it really hangs, it have to be somewhere specific, like blocking OS call.

Comment: My hang was caused by cin returning fail whenever I run the static version. Not sure how to fix it. I did figure out what other DLLs I needed, so now the -static version and the -Bstatic version are doing exactly the same thing. I appreciate the help so far!

Comment: It wasn't related directly to static linking. When static linking, I had to include all of SDL's dependency libraries. Turns out, having -mwindows causes console communication to fail.

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't related directly to static linking. When static linking, I had to include all of SDL's dependency libraries. Turns out, having -mwindows causes console communication to fail.